# Python selenium check if image exists in page

Tags: python, image, selenium, tiktok

I wanna check if image exist on the page with selenium. I tried different ways but everytime i get an error. Like :

```py
from matplotlib.pyplot import text
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import time


socialTexts=[]
def sosyalkontrol(text):
    if socialTexts.__contains__(str(text))==True:
        return False
    else:
        socialTexts.append(text)
        return True

username="testUsername"
op=Options()
op.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:8989")
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Python\\testProject\\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=op)
driver.get("http://tiktok.com/@"+username+"/live")


time.sleep(5)

while True:
    for socialmess in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,('//span[@src="https://p16-webcast.tiktokcdn.com/img/maliva/webcast-va/802a21ae29f9fae5abe3693de9f874bd~tplv-obj.png"]')):
                    print(socialmess.text)
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the page containing that image?

Comment: u can acces it on any tiktok live stream who recipient gift. Im trying to print coming gifts to the streamer

Comment: Can you give us a sample link for that?

Comment: https://www.tiktok.com/@hakkibulut.official/live Like in that stream, when he get a gift u can see in chat. And i can take the source code but cant get that img

Comment: OK, I see that element. Please share ALL your code and clarify what problems do you have

Comment: https://justpaste.it/3e87u This is my code and when i run it i get a "is not a valid 
XPath expression." error code.

Comment: Your code should be here, in your question

Comment: I edited it now u can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code line

```py
for socialmess in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,('//span[@src="https://p16-webcast.tiktokcdn.com/img/maliva/webcast-va/802a21ae29f9fae5abe3693de9f874bd~tplv-obj.png"]')):
```

You are using redundant parenthesis.
It should be

```py
for socialmess in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//span[@src="https://p16-webcast.tiktokcdn.com/img/maliva/webcast-va/802a21ae29f9fae5abe3693de9f874bd~tplv-obj.png"]'):
```

There.
Also I'm not completely sure you are using a correct locator. I couldn't find any element matching that locator on that page. Not on other similar pages.

Comment: It's img instead of span on that page.

Comment: OK, have you tried my solution with changing from span to img?

Comment: Not yet will test when on computer.

Comment: OK, let me know when you tried